# How to get noexcept-ness of a FunctionDecl in clang?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, noexcept, libtooling

I'm currently implementing a clang tool. I have no idea how to find out the noexcept-ness of a function given its `clang::FunctionDecl`. For the following code

```cpp
struct X {
  X() = default;
};

int main() {
  X x;
}
```

`clang-query` shows that the default constructor of `X` is `noexcept`:

```
-CXXConstructorDecl 0x563b8aea50e8 <line:2:3, col:15> col:3 used constexpr X 'void () noexcept' default trivial implicit-inline
 `-CompoundStmt 0x563b8aea5768 <col:15>
```

but `fd->getExceptionSpecType()` returns `clang::ExceptionSpecificationType::EST_None`. Moreover, I think the noexcept-ness might also be encoded in the function type (since it is part of the function type since C++17), but I don't know how to extract that information.

Comment: Can you use the [`noexcept` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept)?  Like `if (noexcept(X())) cout << "Yep, it is noexcept\n";`

Comment: @Eljay The problem is in the development of a clang tool (using clang compiler frontend APIs), not in the C++ source code. `clang::FunctionDecl` is the AST node representing a function declaration, and I want to know whether the function being declared is `noexcept`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `ExceptionSpecificationType` of a
[`FunctionDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html),
call
[`ValueDecl::getType()`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ValueDecl.html)
to get its
[`QualType`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1QualType.html),
call `getTypePtr()` on that to get its
[`Type`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Type.html),
then use
[`dyn_cast`](https://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates)
to downcast that to a
[`FunctionProtoType`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionProtoType.html),
and finally call
`FunctionProtoType::getExceptionSpecType()`.

For example:

```
clang::FunctionDecl const *functionDecl = /*wherever*/;
clang::Type const *type = functionDecl->getType().getTypePtr();
if (auto fpt = dyn_cast<clang::FunctionProtoType>(type)) {
  clang::ExceptionSpecificationType est = fpt->getExceptionSpecType();
  // Now do something with 'est'.
}
```

On your example, for `X::X()`, the above yields `EST_BasicNoexcept`.

(I'm using Clang+LLVM-16.0.0 on Linux, but this should be the same
across a fairly wide range of versions.)

### Why doesn't FunctionDecl::getExceptionSpecType work?

The documentation for `FunctionDecl::getExceptionSpecType()` says:

> Gets the ExceptionSpecificationType as declared.

The "as declared" part means it only includes `noexcept` if that was
syntactically present.

In contrast, by going through the `FunctionProtoType`, we get implicit
exception specifications too.

### Caveat: Unevaluated exception specifications

If you remove the `main` function from the example, then the above
snippet instead yields `EST_Unevaluated`, whose documentation says:

> not evaluated yet, for special member function

Digging through the sources (e.g.,
[`SemaExceptionSpec.cpp:1056`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang/lib/Sema/SemaExceptionSpec.cpp#L1056),
etc.), it seems that implicit exception specifications for constructors
and the like are not computed until needed.  A call site is a "need", as
is a virtual override, perhaps among a few other cases.

### Supplementary

If you want to go deeper on exception specifications, you may want to
look at
[`ExceptionAnalyzer.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/utils/ExceptionAnalyzer.cpp)
in the Clang sources, since that does a bunch of analysis of exception
specification semantics.